# Locked out of my computer after disabling the netword card

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, active-directory, windows-domain

So I made a big mistake : I was doing some tests on my work computer and I disabled the network card (via Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections) and forgot to re-enable it before turning off the computer. I realized well too late that I will be locked out of the computer tomorrow because it won't be connected to the work domain. I have administrative rights on my account, but I need to be connected to use it and I'm pretty sure there is no local admin account.
I guess my question is : is there any way to get that network card enabled again?

Comment: You don't need your network adapter a local account

Comment: You might be able to log in if your admin allows domain logins to be cached. By default they are

Answer (score 0):

How did you connect to your work computer, logon directly or use RDC?

As I know, most domain sets the roaming profile and also catch locally of the domain account, you can still logon locally without network connection if you have the computer on your side.

But if you use RDC to connect your work computer, i am afraid you have to connect the administrator of your company to help to do so.

Enable build in administrator account by following steps, make a local logon with this account to enable network:

http://www.howtogeek.com/75470/how-to-enable-the-hidden-windows-7-admin-account-using-the-registry/

Hope this could be helpful.